# Downloaded bitmap images display too small

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. Every row has a Pokémon sprite that I download to a bitmap, the sprites are always 96 x 96. I manually downloaded a dummy image and put it in my drawables folder, and it renders fine:
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pcWV.png)

But when I actually download the images programmatically, it gives me this result:
[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSXw1.png)

Why are then suddenly so small? When I sysout the height and width of the downloaded bitmaps, it says 96 x 96, but it clearly doesn't render as 96 x 96.

Here's the code of the task that downloads the image

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bm;
    }

}
```

How I call the task

```
try {
        Bitmap bm = new DownloadImageTask().execute(dataModel.getSpriteUrl()).get();
        viewHolder.sprite.setImageBitmap(bm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Pokemon row XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_sprite"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_cp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_gendershiny"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="DELETE"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I realize you are having an issue with displaying the image, but do not (!) use `.get()` with an `AsyncTask` this actually blocks the UI thread until the `AsyncTask` completes. Using `get() is an Anti-Pattern...I have no idea what compelled Google to include this method in the class...Have a look at the docs --> [AsyncTask -- get method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get())

Comment: Please post the xml layout for the list so we can see how the `ImageView` is constrained with in the parent view.

Comment: I know get() blocks the thread, but my code is so much spaghetti-like that I don't know how to do it otherwise... I edited my question and added the XML of the row

Comment: You might want to consider using a `ConstrainLayout` schema instead of `LinearLayout` it will give you more control. I will see if I can find a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this website. I gives some helpful tips of how to use the `scaleType` attribute with the `ImageView`:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

**Please see the edit at the bottom of this answer.**

---

Now to the issue with using `get()` method of an `AsyncTask`

Use an `interface` to let you know when the `AsyncTask` is complete:

```
public interface BitmapLoaderListener {

    void onCompletedBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bm);
}
```

Your `AsyncTask` could look like this:

```
public class BitmapLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    private static final String TAG = BitmapLoader.class.getSimpleName();

    private BitmapLoaderListener mListener;
    private String imageUrl = "";


    public BitmapLoader(String imageUrl, BitmapLoaderListener listener){
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.selectedSource = source;
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bm = null;

        try{
            // Your code here !!!
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }

        return bm;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
        mListener.onCompletedBitmapLoaded(bm);
    }
}
```

Call the `AsyncTask` from your `RecyclerView` from the `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    MyData data = mData.get(position);

    // Add whatever code you need here

    BitmapLoaderListener listener = new BitmapLoaderListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletedBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bm) {
            if (bm == null) return;
            holder.myImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    };

    BitmapLoader loader = new BitmapLoader(imageUrl, listener);
    loader.execute();
}
```

---

You could implement a cache type system where you persist the images to the device storage and load them from the internet only when needed. I do this with a lot of my apps. This is possible, but it requires experience with dealing with threads and resources... As Angelina pointed out you can always use Glide or Picasso libraries. Although I very rarely use third party libraries in this case you might want to consider it--they are well designed and well maintained libraries.

---

**Edit:**

Using a scaling method `createScaledBitmap()`for every downloaded image seems a bit heavy weight.

You might want to make this simple change to your layout file:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/img_sprite"
   android:layout_width="96dp"
   android:layout_height="96dp" 
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

There are many ways to achieve the result you want by making some changes to your layout file. I just pick the easiest with regard to the image size you are downloading (96x96).

This example takes the image and forces it into an `ImageView` 96dpx96dp so that the image is centered and scaled to fit the view bounds maintaining the original aspect ratio.

This is much easier to maintain and modify as well as much more light weight then using `createScaledBitmap()` method for every image--rather it needs it or not, ouch!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I found a workaround for the image sizes, I use `createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, filter)` to simply make the bitmap bigger, it works fine. As for the AsyncTasks, I would like to apply your method but I'm not sure how to integrate it in my code. This is the tutorial that I followed to make my recycler ListView with a custom adapter: https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial My AsyncTask class is inside my Adapter class, and I also make the call inside my Adapter class in the method `getView()`

Comment: Also I initally didn't want to use `execute().get()` and block the thread. But I don't know how to access my ImageView inside the `onPostExecute()` method :/ I'm a total newbie in Android development, I'm making this app for a school task

Comment: @M.Benamar :: Please see the edit at the bottom of my answer. It might be a quick solution to you issue. If not just let me know and I will post a more detailed answer.

Comment: I applied your code and it does render well, thank you! But there's not much difference performance-wise, it still blocks the UI thread for 5 seconds. Would you mind helping me to change my code so that I change the imageViews in the `onPostExecute()` or anything alike? So that the rows already display without waiting for all sprites to load. I edited my post and added all the relevant code, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905844/performance-issue-downloading-images-for-recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

Using AsyncTask to download an image is not the common thing. Usually this is done with a library called `Glide`. It downloads the image in background thread and caches it. You can also set ScaleType of the image there.

Comment: Thank you but, I don't want alternatives, I want this code to work if you know why it is too small

Comment: Loading bitmaps can be tricky and you can easily get to OutOfMemory exceptions. Why reinvent the wheel when there are already invented solutions

Comment: Using an asynctask to download images isn't that uncommon, and your answer does not come close to helping.  An image library here is unnecessary and wouldn't actually help.

Comment: @GabeSechan AsyncTasks can lead to memory leaks and it’s a substitute to a proper architecture. Background calls should not happen in the Activity or Fragment

Comment: @Angelina only if you do it poorly. I'd be much more worried about oom from a library meant to be general purpose and not liking to minimize memory usage. Volley for example is horrible for downloading images, it takes a ton of memory

Comment: As for not doing background calls in an activity- just wrong. And how do you think the libraries do it? They just start a thread.

Comment: Glide is lifecycle aware and uses more sophisticated way to manage references to image resources http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/resourcereuse.html