# Performance issue downloading images for RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-bitmap

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. Every row has an ImageView that I render using a Bitmap, but my current code blocks the UI thread as I am using `get()` after executing my AsyncTask that downloads the bitmaps. I would like to change my code and access the imageViews in the `onPostExecute()` or something similar. So that the rows already display without waiting for all sprites to load.

Adapter class (download is triggered here)

```
public class PokemonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PokemonPOJO> implements View.OnClickListener{

private ArrayList<PokemonPOJO> dataSet;
Context mContext;
private int lastPosition = -1;

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtCP;
    TextView txtGenderShiny;
    ImageView sprite;
    Button btnDelete;
}

public PokemonAdapter(ArrayList<PokemonPOJO> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_pokemon, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object= getItem(position);
    PokemonPOJO dataModel=(PokemonPOJO)object;

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_delete:
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pokemons").child(dataModel.getUid()).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pokemon removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.remove(dataModel);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    PokemonPOJO dataModel = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_pokemon, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        viewHolder.txtCP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_cp);
        viewHolder.txtGenderShiny = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_gendershiny);
        viewHolder.sprite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_sprite);
        viewHolder.btnDelete = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        result=convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result=convertView;
    }

    lastPosition = position;

    viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());
    viewHolder.txtCP.setText("CP: " + Integer.toString(dataModel.getCP()));
    viewHolder.txtGenderShiny.setText(dataModel.getGender() + (dataModel.isShiny() ? " (Shiny)" : ""));
    viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

    try {
        Bitmap bm = new DownloadImageTask().execute(dataModel.getSpriteUrl()).get();
        viewHolder.sprite.setImageBitmap(bm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    viewHolder.btnDelete.setTag(position);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bm;
    }

}
```

Fragment with ListView

```
public class MyPokemonFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private DatabaseReference pokemonDb;
    private TextView text_noPokemon;
    private ListView listViewPokemon;
    private static PokemonAdapter adapter;
    private populateListViewTask populateListView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mypokemon,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        listViewPokemon = view.findViewById(R.id.list_pokemon);
        text_noPokemon= view.findViewById(R.id.text_noPokemon);

        Query getUserPokemon = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pokemons").orderByChild("userUid").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        getUserPokemon.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if(!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    text_noPokemon.setText("You have not added any Pokémon yet.");
                }
                else {
                    TreeMap<String, Pokemon> pokemons = new TreeMap<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot pokemon : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        pokemons.put(pokemon.getKey(), pokemon.getValue(Pokemon.class));
                    }
                    populateListView = new populateListViewTask();
                    populateListView.execute(pokemons);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(populateListView != null && populateListView.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
            populateListView.cancel(true);
    }

    private class populateListViewTask extends AsyncTask<TreeMap<String, Pokemon>, Void, ArrayList<PokemonPOJO>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<PokemonPOJO> doInBackground(TreeMap<String, Pokemon>... maps) {

            ArrayList<PokemonPOJO> pojos = new ArrayList<>();
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            Iterator it = maps[0].entrySet().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                Pokemon p = (Pokemon)pair.getValue();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + p.getPokedexNr() + "/");
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                    String name = j.getString("name");
                    String spriteUrl = (p.isShiny() ? j.getJSONObject("sprites").getString("front_shiny") : j.getJSONObject("sprites").getString("front_default"));

                    PokemonPOJO pojo = new PokemonPOJO((String)pair.getKey(), p.getPokedexNr(), name, spriteUrl, p.isShiny(), p.getGender(), p.getCP());
                    pojos.add(pojo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    connection.disconnect();
                    try {
                        if (reader != null)
                            reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return pojos;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (ArrayList < PokemonPOJO > pojos) {
            adapter = new PokemonAdapter(pojos, getContext());
            listViewPokemon.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Pokemon row XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_sprite"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_cp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_gendershiny"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="DELETE"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having performance issues because you are calling the `get()` method on your `AsyncTask`. The `get()` method basically causes the main thread to wait until the code in the `AsyncTask` completes execution before the main thread continues executing other instructions. Why Google added this method is curious to say the least. So do this to fix your code.

Create a new Java class file. Name the file "DownloadImageTask" and add this code:

```
public interface DownloadImageListener {
    void onCompletedImageDownload(Bitmap bm);
}


public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static final String TAG = DownloadImageTask.class.getSimpleName();

    private DownloadImageListener mListener;
    private String imageUrl = "";

    public DownloadImageTask(String imageUrl, DownloadImageListener listener){
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bm;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {
        mListener.onCompletedImageDownload(bm);
    }
}
```

If you have any issues adding the public `interface` to the "DownloadImageTask" Java file just create a separate Java file name "DownloadImageListener" and put the `interface` code in there.

Set your code to query the `AsyncTask`. 
Change the `Adapter` code inside your `getView()` from this:

```
try {
    Bitmap bm = new DownloadImageTask().execute(dataModel.getSpriteUrl()).get();
    viewHolder.sprite.setImageBitmap(bm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to this:

```
try {
    DownloadImageListener listener = new DownloadImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletedImageDownload(Bitmap bm) {
            if(bm != null){
                viewHolder.sprite.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
        }
    };

    String imageUrl = dataModel.getSpriteUrl();

    DownloadImageTask downloadImageTask = new DownloadImageTask(imageUrl, listener);
    downloadImageTask.execute();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

This allows your `AsyncTask` to execute and when the `Bitmap` is returned the listener is triggered in the `onPostExecute()` method sending the `Bitmap` to your `ListView` in the `onCompletedImageDownload()` callback method.

**Additional Info:**

To improve performance even further you could create a caching model to save and retrieve images from the device if you have already downloaded them in the past. But that requires some really advanced techniques--and gets really tricky when images you wish to download might change from time to time.