# Android app freezes when getting table from azure mobile apps easy tables

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

How do I get filtered data from Azure easy tables using mobile apps SDK?
I have followed the tutorials (ToDoItem works fine), referenced docs, etc for days on end.  My app freezes when I try to query/filter the table.

In my main activity outside any methods:

```
MobileServiceClient mClient;
MobileServiceTable<RouterTable> mRouterTable;
```

In onCreate:

```
try {
    mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://azurept.azurewebsites.net",
            this);
    mRouterTable = mClient.getTable(RouterTable.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My class to query table in background thread:

```
public class GetMac extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG,"Start Query");
            List<RouterTable> results = mRouterTable
                    .where()
                    .field("serial").eq("101")
                    .select("mac")
                    .execute()
                    .get();
            Log.i(TAG,"Query Complete");
            return results.get(0).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My method to make query when button is clicked:

```
private void onProvisionClicked() {
    try {
        mac = new GetMac().execute().get();
        Log.i(TAG, mac);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat after I click the button:

```
2018-12-26 07:33:58.474 8068-8112/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/MainActivity: Start Query
2018-12-26 07:33:58.703 8068-8104/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-26 07:33:58.967 8068-8104/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
```

That's it!  I am expecting to see the log "Query Complete" and so on... but it never does.

How do I query my Azure easy tables to get data from them?

**UPDATE - WORKING:**

```
public class GetMacTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG,"Start Query");
            List<RouterTable> results = mRouterTable
                    .where()
                    .field("serial").eq("101")
                    .select("mac")
                    .execute()
                    .get();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mac = results.get(0).getMac();
                        Log.i(TAG,"Query Complete - MAC: " + mac);
                    }
                });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void onProvisionClicked() {
    try {
        new GetMacTask().execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2018-12-26 11:35:07.522 9838-9887/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/MainActivity: Start Query
2018-12-26 11:35:07.818 9838-9879/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-26 11:35:08.060 9838-9879/com.solvednetworks.cptool W/networks.cptoo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
2018-12-26 11:35:08.380 9838-9838/com.solvednetworks.cptool I/MainActivity: Query Complete - MAC: 00:30:44:22:12:34
```

Comment: You should not call `get()` on `Future`s on UI thread, that will lead to UI block. Use `Activity::runOnUiThread`.

Comment: I pretty much answered this the other day. Take a look at my answer. It pertains to downloading images, but it is analogous to your issue:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905844/performance-issue-downloading-images-for-recyclerview/53906359#53906359

Comment: @M. Prokhorov - It took me a bit to understand that, but I am now only calling .execute() on the asynctask from the main thread, and doing the rest inside of a runnable on the UI thread inside the doInBackground() method, and IT WORKS!  I am going to update the question with my now-working code, please let me know if you see any other problems with it.  THANK YOU! (I have spent days trying to figure this out!)

Comment: @Barns Thank you as well, sir!  I wish I could have found your question but I was searching other terms (like my question topic).

Comment: I just assumed that your `GetMacTask` class was in its own file since you declared it as a `public class`. It makes no sense to have an inner class `AsyncTask`  declared `public`. It also makes very little sense to use `runOnUiThread()` inside the `doInBackground()` method of the `AsyncTask`! Why? Because the `AsyncTask` already provides a method to return the results to the UI thread--and that is the `onPostExecute()`. All instructions carried out in the `onPostExecute()` method are performed on the UI thread. Best of Luck!

Comment: @Barns Thanks again - you can probably tell from my code that I'm new to Java, so that helps tremendously - I know just enough to understand what you are saying, haha.  Also, after the endless hours of trial and error, my code is in a pretty bad state and needs cleaned up now that I understand the root problem I was having.  Thanks for the advice - I'll move this class to it's own java file (is it ok to just use an inner class? I will read up on that) and use onPostExecute() instead of runOnUiThread().  Good stuff, rock on!